# TCP buffering on Linux

Tags: tcp, linux-kernel

I have a peripheral over USB that is sending data samples at a rate of 183 MBit/s. I would like to send this data over ethernet, which is limited to < 100 Mbit/s. Is it possible to send this data without overflow (i.e missing data) by increasing the TCP socket buffer?

Comment: Does the device generate this data with same speed for all time? Buffering can't change Ethernet speed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It also depends on the receiver window size.  Even if there is 100mbits, sender will push data depending on the window size available on the receiver. TCP window size without scaling enabled can go only upto 64kb. In your case, this size is not sufficient as it needs at least (100-183Mbits)10MB buffer.  In Windows 7 & newer Linux OS, TCP by default enables window scaling which can extend the size upto 1GB. After enabling the TCP window scaleing option, you can increase the socket buffer to a bigger size say 50MB which should provide the required buffering.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is, it depends.

Increasing buffers (at transmitter) can help if the data is bursty. If the average rate is <100MBit (actually less, you need to allow for network contention and overhead), then buffering can help. You can do this by increasing the size of the buffers internally to the TCP stack, or by buffering internally to your application.

If the data isn't bursty, or the average is still too high, you might need to compress the data before transmission. Dependant on the nature of the data, you may be able to achieve significant compression.